# How can you increase notification size?

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, push-notifications

I have a Samsung Galaxy S8 and I get notifications which are a bit longer than can be displayed.  For example

> Helen wants you know that there are items waiting for you

will be displayed as

> Helen wants you to know that there are...

Is there a way to increase the size of the notification so the complete notification can be read?

Comment: [Nevolution] (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.nevo) expands notifications to multi line text but may not work with all apps. Try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pull down the notifications or tap the arrow down to expand the full message or notifications